# How the second law of thermodynamics can be rewritten as a relation between temperature, pressure and density?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, cosmology, entropy

I have an exercise in a cosmology course where I'll suppose, that chemical potentials are small i.e. $ |\mu| << T$. Hence, the second law of thermodynamics reads $d(\rho V)=TdS-PdV$.

By comparing the second law with the equation

$dS=\frac{\partial S}{\partial T}dT +\frac{\partial S}{\partial V}dV$

I should show, that the integrability condition

$\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial T \partial V}=\frac{\partial^2 S}{\partial V \partial T}$

leads to the relation

$T \frac{dP}{dT}=\rho +P$.

I have no idea how the integrability condition helps me to obtain the last relation. This far I have rewritten the first relation as

$TdS=d\rho V +(\rho +P)dV$.

Comment: Welcome to Physics SE! Try a [Maxwell relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell_relations), which relies on the [symmetry of second derivatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives) as noted in the problem statement. It's hard to say more because you haven't defined your variables (e.g., $\rho$) and haven't specified what variables are being held constant in $\partial P/\partial T$ and in general. The meaning of "$d\rho V$" is also unclear.